# Does the conductor of an elliptic curve always divide the minimal discriminant?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Of course, the primes dividing the conductor are precisely those dividing the minimal discriminant.  But I cannot find any source that addresses the possibility of a prime appearing to the first power in the minimal discriminant but appearing to the second power in the conductor. Put another way, imagine a square-free discriminant.  Is it possible for some $p$ dividing the discriminant that the curve has additive reduction at $p$?

And to clarify, an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to the question in the title is **yes**. You are looking for Ogg's formula. See Silverman's "Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves", Sections 9, 10, and 11, and in particular Ogg's fomula in 11.1:

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ be a local field and let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve, and let

- $\nu_K(\mathcal{D}_{E/K})$ = the valuation of the minimal discriminant of $E/K$,
- $f(E/K)=$ the exponent of the conductor of $E/K$,
- $m(E/K)=$ the number of components on the special fiber of $E/K$ (thus $m(E/K)\geq 1$).

Then:
$$\nu_K(\mathcal{D}_{E/K})=f(E/K)+m(E/K)-1.$$
In particular, $\nu_K(\mathcal{D}_{E/K})\geq f(E/K)$.

Answer (score 0):

Having tried to work it out some more, I think I have figured it out - the answering being yes (at least in characteristic not $2$ or $3$ and ignoring the primes $2$ and $3$).

Write $$E: y^{2} = x^3 + Ax + b$$ and let $p$ be a prime $> 3$.  Then the discriminant having bad reduction means $4A^{3} + 27B^{2} \equiv 0$ (mod $p$).  Furthermore having additive reduction means $c_{4} \equiv A \equiv 0$ (mod $p)$.  Yet this means that $B \equiv 0$ (mod $p$) so that indeed the discriminant is divisible by $p^{2}$ and the conductor divides it.